# AWS access key id provided does not exist in our records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've an issue with terraform that i really don't understand.

Let me explain :
When i run

- terraform init     all good
- terraform fmt      all good
- terraform validate all good

However when i run terraform plan i get an ERROR
[terraform plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JITs4.png)

I set the **AWS_ACCESS_KEY** & **AWS_SECRET_key** on the code to test it faster ( otherwise the value are passed by gitlab )

If i try **without them** on the **variable.tf** and **use** the **value i export before** to use **AWS CLI** everything work perfecty and i can deploy on aws .

**variable.tf**

```
    variable "aws_region" {
  default = "eu-central-1"
}

variable "bucket_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "test-bucket"
}

variable "aws_access_key" {
  default = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

variable "aws_secret_key" {
  default = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.9.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region     = var.aws_region
  access_key = var.aws_access_key
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_key

  # Make faster by skipping something
  # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#skip_get_ec2_platforms
  skip_get_ec2_platforms      = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_region_validation      = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
}
```

**provider.tf**

```
module "s3-bucket" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.4.0"

  bucket        = var.bucket_name
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = true
  create_bucket = true
  versioning = {
    enabled = true
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration = {
    rule = {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default = {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help guy .
I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: what version of terraform do you use?

Comment: Please post the error as text, an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> **"region"**
>
> **"access_key"**
>
> **"secret_key"**

without

> *aws_*

as the prefix to your variable.tf and main.tf

### *Sometimes it creates conflict with terraform code.*

It looks like the cause is aws_ prefix. When it is used in a variable names this error occurs.

Comment: i use terraform 1.2.6

Comment: i tried without aws _ prefix but it didn't fix the issue :(